# Does markercluster work together with leafletProxy() and option iconCreateFunction?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

Am I doing something wrong, or why does the below example not work? I am trying to make leaflet markercluster plugin work with `leafletProxy()` in an R Shiny app, using the option `iconCreateFunction`. Is the plugin not capable of adding customized icon markers to the map using `leafletProxy()`?

When I press the first button and zoom out in below example, I get an error saying:

> TypeError: this._group.options.iconCreateFunction is not a function

[image]

I tried to copy [the original example](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#customising-the-clustered-markers) from the markercluster documentation:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton(inputId = "my_button1",
                   label = "Use leafletProxy()"),
      actionButton(inputId = "my_button2",
                   label = "Use renderLeaflet()")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput(
        outputId = "map",
        width = "100%",
        height = "300px"
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  some_data <- data.frame(
    "lon"=c(4.905167,4.906357,4.905831),
    "lat"=c(52.37712,52.37783,52.37755),
    "number_var"=c(5,9,7),
    "name"=c("Jane","Harold","Mike"),
    stringsAsFactors = F
  )

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    return(
      leaflet(data = some_data[0,]) %>%
         addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
        fitBounds(
          min(some_data$lon),
          min(some_data$lat),
          max(some_data$lon),
          max(some_data$lat)
        ) %>%
        addMarkers(
          lng = ~lon,
          lat = ~lat,
          clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(
            iconCreateFunction = JS(paste0("function(cluster) {",
                                           "return new L.DivIcon({",
                                           "html: '<div style=\"background-color:rgba(77,77,77,0.5)\"><span>' + cluster.getChildCount() + '</div><span>',",
                                           "className: 'marker-cluster'",
                                           "});",
                                           "}"))



          )
        )
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$my_button1,{
      leafletProxy(mapId = "map",
                   session = session,
                   data = some_data) %>%
        addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
        clearMarkerClusters() %>%
        clearMarkers() %>%
        fitBounds(
          min(some_data$lon),
          min(some_data$lat),
          max(some_data$lon),
          max(some_data$lat)
        ) %>%
        addMarkers(
          lng = ~lon,
          lat = ~lat,
          clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(
            iconCreateFunction = JS(paste0("function(cluster) {",
                                           "console.log('Here comes cluster',cluster); ",
                                           "return new L.DivIcon({",
                                           "html: '<div style=\"background-color:rgba(77,77,77,0.5)\"><span>' + cluster.getChildCount() + '</div><span>',",
                                           "className: 'marker-cluster'",
                                           "});",
                                           "}"))
          )
        )
  })

  observeEvent(input$my_button2,{
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({

      leaflet(data = some_data) %>%
        addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
        fitBounds(
          min(some_data$lon),
          min(some_data$lat),
          max(some_data$lon),
          max(some_data$lat)
        ) %>%
        addMarkers(
          lng = ~lon,
          lat = ~lat,
          clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(
            iconCreateFunction = JS(paste0("function(cluster) {",
                                           "console.log('Here comes cluster',cluster); ",
                                           "return new L.DivIcon({",
                                           "html: '<div style=\"background-color:rgba(77,77,77,0.5)\"><span>' + cluster.getChildCount() + '</div><span>',",
                                           "className: 'marker-cluster'",
                                           "});",
                                           "}"))
          )
        )
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Package versions:

```
dplyr_0.7.4
leaflet_1.1.0
shiny_1.0.5
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
```

Browser version: Firefox Quantum 57.0.1 (64-bit)

[image]

Comment: I don't get any errors while running your code. I am on a mac though.

Comment: You see markers when pressing both buttons? Thanks for trying.

Comment: after pressing leafletProxy() the first time yes, but not after with the zoom out

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly the problem. The markercluser plugin is supposed to organize the zooming, but in case of `leafletProxy` this does not seem to work (although dynamically adding markers to the map would be very useful of course).

Comment: This unanswered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483696/iconcreatefunction-does-not-work-when-adding-markers-with-leafletproxy) suggests this problem has been around awhile and is referenced in two related github issues ([420](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/420) and [440](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/440)) without comment from the team there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Revised solution

The behaviour of `iconCreateFunction` is definitely *flakey* when used within `leafletProxy`. Although I think there is caching in some browsers making it difficult to track visually.

In order to eliminate the *javascript* error you were experiencing, it is important to apply `layerId` and `clusterId` values as well as using `removeMarker` in lieu of `clearMarkers`.

> **N.B.** A strange side-effect of my solution is that a marker is dropped when re-drawn, I'm getting a bit tired and will have another look later. That problem may or may not be trivial.

#### app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton(inputId = "my_button1",
                   label = "Use leafletProxy()"),
      actionButton(inputId = "my_button2",
                   label = "Use renderLeaflet()")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput(
        outputId = "mymap",
        width = "100%",
        height = "300px"
    ))
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  some_data <- data.frame(
    lon = c(4.905167, 4.906357, 4.905831),
    lat = c(52.37712, 52.37783, 52.37755),
    number_var = c(5, 9, 7),
    name = c("Jane", "Harold", "Mike"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

  marker_js <- JS("function(cluster) {
                  var html = '<div style=\"background-color:rgba(77,77,77,0.5)\"><span>' + cluster.getChildCount() + '</div><span>'
                  return new L.DivIcon({html: html, className: 'marker-cluster'});
                  }")

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({

    leaflet(some_data) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
      fitBounds(
        ~min(lon),
        ~min(lat),
        ~max(lon),
        ~max(lat)
      ) %>%
      addMarkers(
        layerId = "mylayer",
        clusterId = "mycluster",
        lng = ~lon,
        lat = ~lat,
        clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(
          iconCreateFunction = marker_js
        )
      )

  })

  observeEvent(input$my_button1, {

    leafletProxy("mymap", data = some_data) %>%
      removeMarker(layerId = "mylayer") %>%
      clearTiles %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
      fitBounds(
        ~min(lon),
        ~min(lat),
        ~max(lon),
        ~max(lat)
      ) %>%
      addMarkers(
        layerId = "mylayer",
        clusterId = "mycluster",
        lng = ~lon,
        lat = ~lat,
        clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(
          iconCreateFunction = marker_js
        )
      )

  })

  observeEvent(input$my_button2,{

    output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({

      leaflet(some_data) %>%
        addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
        fitBounds(
          ~min(lon),
          ~min(lat),
          ~max(lon),
          ~max(lat)
        ) %>%
        addMarkers(
          layerId = "mylayer",
          clusterId = "mycluster",
          lng = ~lon,
          lat = ~lat,
          clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(
            iconCreateFunction = marker_js
          )
        )
    })

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

#### in-browser

[image]

> No other *javascript* errors were noted.

Comment: Thanks for your input; I agree that leaflet maps should be initialized and pre-rendered before manipulation with `leafletProxy()`. Yet my major problem remains: A customized function for option `iconCreateFunction` is not accepted by the plugin when using `leafletProxy()`. I consider that a bug unless I get to know how to use customized create functions for markers that get injected using `leafletProxy()`.

Comment: @nilsole, updated solution following your clarification.

Comment: Thanks. The code above causes errors. 1) Run app. 2) Open Developer Tools / Firebug. 3) Click "Use leafletProxy()". 4) JS error as described above: `Uncaught TypeError: this._group.options.iconCreateFunction is not a function`. Can you reproduce, please?

Comment: Almost perfect, good work. The only question that remains is: Why are only 2 points added to the refreshed proxy map instead of 3? One marker seems to be missing. I tried to alter the `layerId` and `clusterId` on refresh, but without any positive effect.

Comment: I think this turns into a speculative discussion from here, so be rewarded for your discovery and research (I am feeling bad that I did not come up with the links, sorry).

Answer (score 5):

To follow Kevin's answer, modifying the clusterId to a vector gets the leafletProxy version to work for me. Not sure if this causes unintended consequences though...

app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton(inputId = "my_button1",
                   label = "Use leafletProxy()"),
      actionButton(inputId = "my_button2",
                   label = "Use renderLeaflet()")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput(
        outputId = "mymap",
        width = "100%",
        height = "300px"
      ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  some_data <- data.frame(
    lon = c(4.905167, 4.906357, 4.905831),
    lat = c(52.37712, 52.37783, 52.37755),
    number_var = c(5, 9, 7),
    name = c("Jane", "Harold", "Mike"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

  marker_js <- JS("function(cluster) {
                  var html = '<div style=\"background-color:rgba(77,77,77,0.5)\"><span>' + cluster.getChildCount() + '</div><span>'
                  return new L.DivIcon({html: html, className: 'marker-cluster'});
}")

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({

    leaflet(some_data) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
      fitBounds(
        ~min(lon),
        ~min(lat),
        ~max(lon),
        ~max(lat)
      ) %>%
      addMarkers(
        layerId = "mylayer",
        clusterId = "mycluster",
        lng = ~lon,
        lat = ~lat,
        clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(
          iconCreateFunction = marker_js
        )
      )

  })

  observeEvent(input$my_button1, {

    leafletProxy("mymap", data = some_data) %>%
      removeMarker(layerId = "mylayer") %>%
      clearTiles %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
      fitBounds(
        ~min(lon),
        ~min(lat),
        ~max(lon),
        ~max(lat)
      ) %>%
      addMarkers(
        layerId = "mylayer",
        clusterId = ~name,
        lng = ~lon,
        lat = ~lat,
        clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(
          iconCreateFunction = marker_js
        )
      )

  })

  observeEvent(input$my_button2,{

    output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({

      leaflet(some_data) %>%
        addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
        fitBounds(
          ~min(lon),
          ~min(lat),
          ~max(lon),
          ~max(lat)
        ) %>%
        addMarkers(
          layerId = "mylayer",
          clusterId = "mycluster",
          lng = ~lon,
          lat = ~lat,
          clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(
            iconCreateFunction = marker_js
          )
        )
    })

  })

  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who is struggling with this, the bug has been recently solved:
https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/pull/696

You need to reinstall leaflet from github using:

```
remotes::install_github("rstudio/leaflet")
```

and then restart R.