# How to use clusterOptions in shinyapp leaflet map?

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

The following code works fine for common markers.

The clustering markers code works fine outside shiny.

How can I make it work in shiny.

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)

# TRUE, working simple version
simple <- TRUE # change to FALSE FOR non-working desired version

col_feed_con_raw_01_coords <- data.frame(lng = rep(sample(seq(from=-101, to=-99,by=.4), 100, replace = T),3),
                                         lat = rep(sample(seq(from=39, to=41,  by=.4), 100, replace=T),3),
                                         service_type = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 300, replace = T)
)

ser_types <- unique(col_feed_con_raw_01_coords$service_type)
ser_types <- sort(ser_types)

colorList4  <- c('forestgreen',
                 '#ee0000',
                 'orange',
                 'cornflowerblue'
)


ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,
                checkboxGroupInput("service_type",
                                   "Choose service:"
                                   ,choiceNames  = ser_types
                                   ,choiceValues = 1:4
                                   ,selected = 1:4
                )
                ,checkboxInput("allnone",
                               "All/None"
                               ,value=TRUE)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  print(paste0("Running in: ",
               isolate(session$clientData$url_hostname),":"
               ,isolate(session$clientData$url_port))
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$allnone,{
    
    if(input$allnone){
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"service_type",selected = 1:4)
    } else {
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"service_type"
                               ,choiceNames=ser_types
                               ,choiceValues = 1:4
                               ,selected = NULL)
    }
  })
  
  filteredColors <- reactive({
    colorList4[as.numeric(input$service_type) ]
  })
  
  filteredService <- reactive({
    ser_types[as.numeric(input$service_type) ]
  })
  
  filteredData <- reactive({
    col_feed_con_raw_01_coords[which(col_feed_con_raw_01_coords$service_type %in%
                                       filteredService() ), ]
  })
  
  mycolors <- reactive({
    colorFactor(palette = filteredColors()
                ,filteredService()
    )
  })
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    
    leaflet(data = filteredData()
            ,options = leafletOptions(preferCanvas = TRUE) )  %>%
      addTiles(options = providerTileOptions(
        updateWhenZooming = FALSE,
        updateWhenIdle = FALSE) ) %>% setView(lng = -100 #4.65
                                              ,lat = 40  #-74.1
                                              ,zoom = 9)
    
  })
  
  observe({
    if(length(input$service_type) > 0 ) {
      
      pal <- mycolors()
      
      if(simple){
        leafletProxy("map",data = filteredData()) %>% addTiles() %>%
          addCircleMarkers(~lng, ~lat,
                           radius = ~ 10
                           , fillColor = ~pal(service_type)
                           , stroke = FALSE
                           , fillOpacity = 0.7
          )
      }
      if(!simple){
        leafletProxy("map",data = filteredData()
        )  %>% addTiles(
          options = providerTileOptions(
            updateWhenZooming = FALSE,      # map won't update tiles until zoom is done
            updateWhenIdle = FALSE)
        ) %>%
          addCircleMarkers(data = filteredData()
                           ,~lng
                           ,~lat
                           ,clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(
                             iconCreateFunction=JS("function (cluster) {
                          var childCount = cluster.getChildCount();
                          if (childCount < 100) {
                            c = 'rgba(255, 150, 150, 0.5);'
                          } else if (childCount < 500) {
                            c = 'rgba(255, 100, 100, 0.5);'
                          } else {
                            c = 'rgba(255, 50, 50, 0.5);'
                          }
                          return new L.DivIcon({ html: '<div style=\"background-color:'+c+'\"><span>' + childCount + '</span></div>',
                          className: 'marker-cluster'

                          });
                        }"
                             )
                             ,spiderfyOnMaxZoom = TRUE
                           )
                           , fillColor   = ~pal(service_type)
                           , stroke      = FALSE
                           , fillOpacity = 0.7
          ) # aCM
      }
    }
  })
  
  observe({
    
    if(length(input$service_type)>0){
      
      proxy <- leafletProxy("map",data = filteredData() )
      
      pal<-mycolors()
      proxy %>% clearControls()
      proxy %>% addLegend('bottomright',
                          pal = pal,
                          values = ~service_type,
                          title = 'Services:',
                          opacity = 1)
      
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this is not easily possible at the moment as `leafetProxy` cannot work properly with JS in its arguments. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/pull/696) for the leaflet R-package that enables this behaviour, but it has not been merged yet. Apparently it is planned for version 2.1.

The PR says:

> htmlwidgets provides built-in support for the JS function, which lets you mark widget data string values in R to be evaluated as JS code when the widget data is deserialized in the browser. This isn't supported natively in Shiny though, so leafletProxy did not automatically inherit this behavior. The changes in this PR reimplement that mechanism for leafletProxy.

So it seems it is just not supported at the moment.

In the PR [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47922951/does-markercluster-work-together-with-leafletproxy-and-option-iconcreatefuncti) is linked. The accepted answer there claims that there is a workaround, but it is from 2017 and I couldn't get it to work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I saw in the link of @AEF was to recreate the map output:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

{
  col_feed_con_raw_01_coords <- data.frame(lng = rep(sample(seq(from=-101, to=-99,by=.4), 100, replace = T),3),
                                         lat = rep(sample(seq(from=39, to=41,  by=.4), 100, replace=T),3),
                                         service_type = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 300, replace = T)
)

ser_types <- sort(unique(col_feed_con_raw_01_coords$service_type) )

colorList4  <- c('forestgreen',
                 '#ee0000',
                 'orange',
                 'cornflowerblue'
)


ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
  absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,
                checkboxGroupInput("service_type",
                                   "Choose service:"
                                   ,choiceNames  = ser_types
                                   ,choiceValues = 1:4
                                   ,selected = 1:4
                )
                ,checkboxInput("allnone",
                               "All/None"
                               ,value=TRUE)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  print(paste0("Running in: ",
               isolate(session$clientData$url_hostname),":"
               ,isolate(session$clientData$url_port))
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$allnone,{
    
    if(input$allnone){
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"service_type",selected = 1:4)
    } else {
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"service_type"
                               ,choiceNames=ser_types
                               ,choiceValues = 1:4
                               ,selected = NULL)
    }
  })
  
  filteredColors <- reactive({
    colorList4[as.numeric(input$service_type) ]
  })
  
  filteredService <- reactive({
    ser_types[as.numeric(input$service_type) ]
  })
  
  filteredData <- reactive({
    col_feed_con_raw_01_coords[which(col_feed_con_raw_01_coords$service_type %in%
                                       filteredService() ), ]
  })
  
  colors<-colorFactor(palette = colorList4
              ,ser_types
  )
  
  mycolors <- reactive({
    colorFactor(palette = filteredColors()
                ,filteredService()
    )
  })
  
  JSfunction <- JS("function (cluster) {
                          var childCount = cluster.getChildCount();
                          if (childCount < 100) {
                            c = 'rgba(255, 150, 150, 0.5);'
                          } else if (childCount < 500) {
                            c = 'rgba(255, 100, 100, 0.5);'
                          } else {
                            c = 'rgba(255, 50, 50, 0.5);'
                          }
                          return new L.DivIcon({ html: '<div style=\"background-color:'+c+'\"><span>' + childCount + '</span></div>',
                          className: 'marker-cluster'

                          });
                        }"
  )
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    
    pal<-colors
    
    leaflet(data = col_feed_con_raw_01_coords
            ,options = leafletOptions(preferCanvas = TRUE) )  %>%
      addTiles(options = providerTileOptions(
        updateWhenZooming = FALSE,
        updateWhenIdle = FALSE) 
        ) %>% setView(lng = -100 
                      ,lat = 40  
                      ,zoom = 9
            ) %>% addCircleMarkers(data = col_feed_con_raw_01_coords
                       ,~lng
                       ,~lat
                       ,clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(
                         iconCreateFunction= JSfunction
                         ,spiderfyOnMaxZoom = TRUE
                       )
                       , fillColor   = ~pal(service_type)
                       , stroke      = FALSE
                       , fillOpacity = 0.7
      ) # aCM
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(c(input$service_type, input$allnone),{
    
    if(nrow(filteredData() )==0){
      filOrAll <- col_feed_con_raw_01_coords
      pal <- colors
    } else {
     filOrAll<- filteredData()
     pal <- mycolors()
    }
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        
        leaflet(data = filOrAll
                     
        )  %>% addTiles(
          options = providerTileOptions(
            updateWhenZooming = FALSE,      # map won't update tiles until zoom is done
            updateWhenIdle = FALSE)
        ) %>%
          addCircleMarkers(data = filOrAll
                           ,~lng
                           ,~lat
                           ,clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(
                             iconCreateFunction=JSfunction
                             ,spiderfyOnMaxZoom = TRUE
                           )
                           , fillColor   = ~pal(service_type)
                           , stroke      = FALSE
                           , fillOpacity = 0.7
          ) # aCM
      })
      
  
  })
  
  observe({
    
    if(length(input$service_type)>0 & nrow(filteredData()>0 ) ) {
      
      proxy <- leafletProxy("map", data = filteredData() )
      
      pal <- mycolors()
      
      proxy %>% clearControls()
      proxy %>% addLegend('bottomright',
                          pal = pal,
                          values = ~service_type,
                          title = 'Services:',
                          opacity = 1)
      
    }
  })
}
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```