# R - Leaflet doesn't display custom Cluster Markers when map is embed in a Shiny app and rendered through observer

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, icons, cluster-computing

In Shiny, I have produced a leaflet map with clustered markers, and the cluster icon is a custom one, defined by me through JavaScript (`JS()` function). **Such map should be reactive** based on user inputs in a `radioButton()`. Hence, I used an `observer()` with an if statement, updating the map through `leafletProxy()`.

When the icon of the cluster is a custom one, and not Leaflet's default, the marker cluters don't even appear. It seems that `leafletProxy()` can't handle the "reactivity" of the `observer()`. Below a minimal reproducible example.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(

br(),

  radioButtons(inputId = "markers",
               label = NULL,
               choices = c("Type A",
                           "Type B"),
               selected = "Type A"),

br(),

  leafletOutput(outputId = "map")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({

    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lng = 178.441895,
              lat = -18.141600,
              zoom = 3.5)
  })

  observe({

    if (input$markers == "Type A") {

      leafletProxy(mapId = "map") %>%

        clearMarkerClusters() %>%

        addMarkers(data = quakes,
                   lng = ~long,
                   lat = ~lat,
                   clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())

    } else {

      leafletProxy(mapId = "map") %>%

        clearMarkerClusters() %>%

        addMarkers(data = quakes,
                   lng = ~long,
                   lat = ~lat,
                   clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(iconCreateFunction = JS("function (cluster) {
                                                                               return new L.Icon({iconUrl: 'https://nicocriscuolo.github.io/resistancebank_plots/markers/marker_3D.png',
                                                                               iconSize: [18, 27],
                                                                               iconAnchor: [10, 26],
                                                                               shadowUrl: 'https://nicocriscuolo.github.io/resistancebank_plots/markers/shadow-marker_3D.png',
                                                                               shadowSize: [26, 39],
                                                                               shadowAnchor: [5, 28]});}")))

    }

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What could be a possible solution?

Comment: Having trouble figuring this out, see if this helps in any way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47922951/does-markercluster-work-together-with-leafletproxy-and-option-iconcreatefuncti

Comment: I have already tried, but unfortunately this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has finally been solved by Joe Cheng. Solution here:

https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/pull/696

Make sure to install the updated **leaflet** version through:

`remotes::install_github("rstudio/leaflet")`